# MongoDb projection depending on another (boolean) field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection where every object has an `anonymous` boolean field. If it is `true` then I want the `owner` field to be filtered out (in my collection it's actually an array of owners).

Is there a way of including this restriction directly in the projection? Something like this:

`MyCollection.find({}, {$if: {owners: anonymous} })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command like this:

```
MyCollection.aggregate([{$project: {owner: {$cond: ["$anonymous", null, "$owner"]}}}]);
```

It does not filter out the owner field, but sets it to null.